# Maintaining relationship between XML nodes. SQL. XPath

Tags: sql, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I am trying to pull data from an XML file using SQL / XPath

For my example lets say that the table is called [Books] and the column that contains the XML is called [XML]

Example XML:

```
<Books>
 <Book>
  <Title>Apology</Title>
  <Author>Socrates</Author>
 </Book>
 <Book>
  <Title>Republic</Title>
  <Author>Plato</Author>
 </Book>
 <Book>
  <Title>Politics</Title>
  <Author>Aristotle</Author>
 </Book>
</Books>
```

Desired Result:

| Title | Author |
| --- | --- |
| Apology | Socrates |
| Republic | Plato |
| Politics | Aristotle |

I am able to pull the distinct 'Titles' with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
a.x.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Title'
FROM [dbo].[Books]
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('//Books/Book/Title') AS a (x)
```

Result:

| Title |
| --- |
| Apology |
| Republic |
| Politics |

However, I am unable to pull the other nodes while maintaining their relationship with eachother.

For example, if i add a second 'Cross Apply':

```
SELECT 
a.x.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Title',
b.x.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Author'
FROM [dbo].[Books]
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('//Books/Book/Title') AS a (x)
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('//Books/Book/Author') AS b (x)
```

The result will be something like this:

| Title | Author |
| --- | --- |
| Apology | Socrates |
| Apology | Plato |
| Apology | Aristotle |
| Republic | Plato |
| Republic | Socrates |
| Republic | Aristotle |
| Politics | Aristotle |
| Politics | Plato |
| Politics | Socrates |

I have also tried to pull both nodes using one cross apply:

```
SELECT 
a.x.value('(//Title/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Title',
a.x.value('(//Author/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Author'
FROM [dbo].[Books]
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('//Books/Book') AS a (x)
```

When i try this i just get the first node duplicated:

| Title | Author |
| --- | --- |
| Apology | Socrates |
| Apology | Socrates |
| Apology | Socrates |

Is there any way i can preserve the relationship between these 2 nodes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular instance, you don't need to correlate anything. You can just shred the `Books/Book` node, then select each value separately

```sql
SELECT 
  x1.Book.value('(Title/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Title,
  x1.Book.value('(Author/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Author
FROM dbo.Books b
CROSS APPLY b.XML.nodes('Books/Book') AS x1 (book);
```

If you really need to correlate them (for example if there are multiple `Title` nodes), you can just pass the result of one `.nodes` to the next

```sql
SELECT 
  x2.Title.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Title,
  x3.Author.value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Author
FROM dbo.Books b
CROSS APPLY b.XML.nodes('Books/Book') AS x1 (Book)
CROSS APPLY x1.Book.nodes('Title') AS x2 (Title)
CROSS APPLY x1.Book.nodes('Author') AS x3 (Author);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/h3dgzyF4)

Also note that the `//` all-descendants axis is slow, and you should favour the `/` direct-child axis if possible.

Comment: Aha! My situation was a bit more complicated than the examples i gave, but the second solution (passing the results from one cross apply to the next) works great.
Can't thank you enough:)